# Change CSS property value using signed values

Tags: html, css

I am having a HTML content like this.

[image: The Box Model]

It has a padding of 70. I tried to reduce the padding by adding using another css rule like this

`padding-top: -20px !important`

All I want to do is, already existing property value 70px should be added with the additional rule -20px so the result should be 50px.

I am able to accomplish this by doing `padding-top: 50px !important`

But still I want to do this mathematical calculations in the css as I asked. Please help.

**Note: The already existing value is in separate css rule and this added one is in separate rule.**

Comment: You probably need to use a preprocessor  (SASS/SCSS/LESS) to do what you want (or like the next comment - `calc()`)

Comment: I would suggest trying `calc()` https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/

Comment: Native CSS is not great at this. I suggest looking into a CSS preprocessor like LESS or SASS

Comment: fauxserious your suggestion is a good one, however be aware of browser support of calc, also sibidharan I am not aware of a simple method to evaluate the current value and change it, the easiest approach would probably using some JS e.g. jQuery get the current value and subtract the necessary amount, but that depends on the use case of course

Comment: you should **not** use negative `padding`

Comment: There is no way with CSS as what you're trying to do but calc is what you need but still you have to provide it there which is just not you do. Instead you just override it with new padding value. And negative values in padding doesn't work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can't be done without calc method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do cross class calculations in CSS

If you want to do mathematical calculations of any kind, check out the `calc()` function

It allows you to do things like: `padding-top: calc(10em - 60px)`

As long as you're not using it for `background-position`; calc should be backwards compatible to IE9 and work on pretty much any other browser bar Opera Mini

Comment: I want to do that calculation with the existing property value. Any way?

Comment: with JavaScript yes!

Comment: JS or as suggested in the comments, using a preprocessor. SASS or LESS will allow you define variables and perform more complex calculations than CSS alone will. The catch is, it's not what gets sent to the client browser. It will generate the final CSS based on what you write and you will use that (generated CSS) in your page/site